# Apply filter before every query builder call for a model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, query-builder

Is it possible to apply a filter every time you want to query a specific model? So instead of writing something like this every time:

```
User::where('exclude', false)->all();
User::where('exclude', false)->first();
User::where('exclude', false)->where(...);
...
```

you could include that where clause in the model itself? The result would make the above queries look like this:

```
User::all();
User::first();
User::where(...);
...
```

making all users with the field `exclude` set as true not appear in the query results.

Furthermore, could it also work in every relation that references the model? For example:

```
$post->user();
$group->users();
```

Not sure how to approach this. For a start, i tried overriding a single method like this:

```
public static function all($columns = []) {
    return self::where('exclude', false)->get($columns);
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to do anything. Also, even if it did, it would only affect query calls which specifically use the `all()` method, and not others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about a global scope: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#global-scopes

It would look like this:

```
class User extends Model
{

  protected static function boot()
  {
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('exclude', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->where('exclude', false);
    });
  }
}
```

This impacts any query for this model.  You can remove it on the fly if you need to:

```
User::withoutGlobalScope('exclude')->get();
```

Comment: brilliant! for future reference - note that removing the global scope also works on relationships without issues: `$group->users()->withoutGlobalScope('exclude');`